# Netbeans 11.1 print numbers in Windows's default language

Tags: java, netbeans

I am still learning Java using Netbeans 11.1.

My problem is when I try to run a program that should display numbers, I get the numbers printed in Arabic which is my Windows default language.

This is what I get as a result:

[image: NetBeans output window]

I added the line: `-J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US`
to the **netbeans.conf** file, but that did not solve the problem.

Another solution suggested using `scanner.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);`
but I could not understand how and where to use it. This is my code:

```
package lesson02;

public class ProvidedVariablesOneStatement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Khalid"; name
        int age = 24;
        double gpa = 3.40;
        System.out.printf("%s is %d years old. %s has %f gpa. \n", name, age, name, gpa);
    }
}
```

The `name` is printed in English letters without any problem, but the `age` and `gpa` are printed in Arabic numbers. The output is:

`Khalid is ٢٤ years old. Khalid has ٣٫٤٠٠٠٠٠ gpa.`

Comment: You should say "Eastern Arabic numbers" ٢٤, because these "24" are called "Western Arabic numbers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render the numbers in your output using Western Arabic Numerals you just need to explicitly set the `Locale` appropriately within your application.

Here is a slightly modified version of your program which first displays the information using Eastern Arabic numerals, and then displays the same information using Western Arabic numerals.

```
package javaapplication18;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class JavaApplication18 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = "Khalid";
        int age = 24;
        double gpa = 3.40;

        Locale arLocale = new Locale("ar");
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(arLocale);
        System.out.println("Country: " + arLocale.getCountry() + ", Language: " + arLocale.getLanguage());
        System.out.printf("%s is %s years old. %s has %s gpa. \n",
                name, nf.format(age), name, nf.format(gpa));

        Locale usLocale = new Locale("us", "EN");
        nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(usLocale);
        System.out.println("Country: " + usLocale.getCountry() + ", Language: " + usLocale.getLanguage());        
        System.out.printf("%s is %s years old. %s has %s gpa. \n",
                name, nf.format(age), name, nf.format(gpa));
    }
}
```

This is what is displayed in the **Output** window in NetBeans:

```
Country: , Language: ar
Khalid is ٢٤ years old. Khalid has ٣٫٤ gpa. 
Country: EN, Language: us
Khalid is 24 years old. Khalid has 3.4 gpa.
```

Notes:

- See the [Oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html) for an introduction to locales.
- See the Javadocs for [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) and [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) for more details.
- You should also be able to set locale within **netbeans.conf**, but I chose to do it programmatically to show the effect of switching it dynamically.
- The **Output** window in NetBeans must be configured to use a font to support the language you are using for output. Obviously this is not an issue for you.